# How to use a completion block and then get the data into TableView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to this so have just been learning about completion blocks, but I am unsure of how to do so in such a way that I get the data to then be apart of a tableview. I have seen other questions related, but regarding older versions of Swift.

I want the table view to contain all the fruit names collected from my database.

I have initialised an empty array list like so:

```
    
    var fruitNames : [String] = []
```

Then fetch the data from my firestore database

```
    func getNames(){
   
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("fruits").getDocuments() {(snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error!")
    

            } else {

                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let name = document.get("name") as! String
            
                    self.fruitNames.append(name)

                    //completion needed
         
      
                   
                }

            }
   
        }
           
        

    }
}
```

I have an extension added on for my tableView

```
extension FruitsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        fruitNames.count
       
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = self.fruitNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
        
       
        
    }
    

    
}
```

Comment: At the end of the completion block do `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.fruitNames.reloadData()  }`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your completion block, you need to tell your table view to update by calling the `reloadData()` method. In your class, you should have a variable holding your tableView.  So, your `getName` should look like

```
 func getNames(){
   
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("fruits").getDocuments() {(snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error!")
    

            } else {

                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let name = document.get("name") as! String
            
                    self.fruitNames.append(name)

                    //completion needed
         
      
                   
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use [weak self] in closure. Otherwise it can lead to memory leak or crashes. You should read about

- automatic reference counting and memory management
- closures (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

If you want to display fruit names, you should call .reloadData() on your tableView object. Then, all delegate methods like numberOfRowsInSection or cellForRowAt will be called again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

1. You have to take an escaping closure as a parameter to the getName() method, which would return Void :

   func getName(onComplition: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ dataList: [String]) -> Void) {

   ```
   let db = Firestore.firestore()

   db.collection("fruits").getDocuments() {(snapshot, error) in
       if let error = error {
           print("There was an error!")
           onComplition(true, [])

       } else {
           var data = [String]()
           for document in snapshot!.documents {

               let name = document.get("name") as! String
               data.append(name) // Here data is local variable.

           }
           onComplition(true, data)
       }

   }
   ```

   }
2. in `ViewDidLoad()`

> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     self.getName { [weak self] (isSuccess, dataList) in
>         guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
>         weakSelf.fruitNames = dataList // fruitNames is your TableViewController's instance variable
>         weakSelf.tableView.reloadData()
>     }
> }
> ```

I have written it directly in IDE, please ignore if there's any syntax error

Answer (score 1):

If you have written perfect code to fetch fruit names.

But your table view is already initialized and loaded with default/empty items in the table view.

You have fetched data after the table view loaded.

So solution is you have to reload your table view again.

So in the closure (After fetching and appending your data to an array) just reload the table view like below and it reloads fresh data.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

User `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` for closure to avoid retain cycles and it causes memory issues.